# How to solve this irrational inequality with different signs?

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality:

$$x\geq-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3x^2+4}$$

My first impulse is to square it, but firstly, $x$ can have any sign. And secondly, the right part is negative.

I have no idea what to do, please help. Or at the least give me a hint.

Comment: If $x$ is non-negative, then the inequality is true. What if it is negative?

Comment: You don't understand, I must preserve the same interval when it's squared. I used this inequality to find domain of equation ("область допустимых значений" as we say in Russian, I'm not sure that "domain" is right term in English) and squared it. For this reason I lost solution x=0 of my equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes squaring is correct! Note that the inequality clearly holds when $x\ge0$, so consider when $x=-k$, where $k$ is a positive real number. Then

$$x\ge-0.5\sqrt{3x^2+4}\implies k\le0.5\sqrt{3k^2+4}\implies k^2\le0.25(3k^2+4)=0.75k^2+1...$$ I'm sure you can go on.

Comment: Wait a minute. Do you go from "x >" to "k <" by just multiplying by -1? If yes, then I would approve of it if I was sure that x can't be positive. But x can be positive. And in this case your multiplication will make inequality unsuitable for squaring. We need to handle both cases at the same time, thus we can't just multiply the inequality by -1.

Comment: Yes. You must switch the direction of the inequality when you multiply by a negative sign. And I did consider both cases, when x is non-negative and when $x$ is negative... and note that it is very easy to see that the inequality holds when $x\ge0$ since the right hand side is negative (whereas the left is positive/zero)!

Comment: "is very easy to see that the inequality holds when x=>0" I don't like this "when" word. Because sign of x isn't some kind of secret that we must discover, "it's either positive or negative", it's BOTH at the same time.  Like Shrodinger's cat that is both dead and alive. Analog: a+a=2*a, no matter if a>0, a<0 or a=0.

Answer (score 0):

If $$x\geq 0$$ then our inequality is true.
For $$x<0$$ we get:
$$-x\le \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3x^2+4}$$
Now all is positive and we get by squaring
$$4x^2\le 3x^2+4$$
$$x^2\le 4$$
So?

Comment: "If x>0 then our inequality is true", yep, but it become false if you will square it. Take x=1 for example.

Comment: No, for $x<0$ we multiply by $-1$ and so is $-x>0$!

Comment: I'm not talking about x<0, I'm talking about x>0. (Although how can we know in advance that x is positive or negative? )

Comment: We are doing case work, $x$ can be positive or negative or zero, other cases do not exist.!

Comment: I just want to point out that we can get nonsense after squaring even with x>0. For example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%E2%89%A5(-0.5%E2%88%9A(3*1%5E2%2B4))%5E2   "Now all is positive and we get by squaring" It works when x is negative, but will fail when x is positive already.

Comment: By "fail" I mean "become unsuitable for squaring due to different signs"

Comment: This have i not done.